# Code worked for sample run but fails on submission: Hackerrank problem

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem and my code fails on submission. Clears only 5 out of 15 test cases. I think it has something related to using 64 bit integers. I do not have any knowledge about that and what is causing my program to fail.

The program below shows my approach

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) 
{
    int l = arr.size();
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    long long int min = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    long long int max = arr[l - 1] + arr[l - 2] + arr[l - 3] + arr[l-4];
    cout<<min<<" "<<max<<endl;
}
```

the compiler says wrong output. I do not know what i am doing wrong please help.

Comment: `long long int min = arr[0] + arr[1] + ...;` does the calculation with `int`s, and converts the final result to `long long`. You probably want something like `long long int min = (long long)arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + ...;`.

Comment: thanks it passed all test cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are computing the value on the left as an `int` and then assigning it to `unsigned long long`.

To prevent from overflow you should cast at least one of the values to `unsigned long long`.

```
long long int min = static_cast<long long int>(arr[0]) + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
```

Same goes if you are using `double` for example and see the same behavior.

Comment: Yes understood, thanks..i just wanted to ask when do you use static cast and when do you just place the type to used for casting in parenthesis like in the comment above. Is there a difference between the two.

Comment: @ShivamSingh in cpp there are a few types of casting that perform different things.
The idea is that you explicitly say what cast you want to perform. 
Casting with just parenthesis is called c-style cast and can perform all of the casts.
You should not use it if you are writing quality cpp code.